# How to remove space at the beginning of a tcolorbox in a beamer block?

Tags: beamer, tcolorbox, beamerarticle

I am using the `tcolorbox` package to produce some blocks in a document. I use beamer and beamerarticle to produce both the slides and a kind of manuscript linked to the presentation.

If you look at the pictures below, you will see that both in article mode and in beamer mode, in the block inside an environnement `example block` of beamer there is a space at the beginning of the text in the `tcolorbox`. That space seems to not be there if I use a `tcolorbox` directly. Is there a way to remove it ?

Here it what it looks like in beamer mode, you can see the space.

[image: in beamer mode]

And there it is what it looks like in article mode. Compare the two blocks, the first one is out of an `example block` (directly with tcolorbox and the space is not there), the second one is inside an `example block` (and there is a space).

[image: in beamer article mode]

Hereafter is the MWE that produces the two above images.

```
% \documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}

\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2]{
    lower separated=false,
    colback=white,
    colframe={#2},
    fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries,
    % fontupper=\bfseries\sffamily,
    colbacktitle={#2},
    coltitle=white,
    before upper=\par\noindent{},
    enhanced,
    attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-0.1in,xshift=0.15in},
    boxed title style={boxrule=0pt,colframe=white,},
    title={\color{white}{#1}}
}
\setbeamertemplate{block example begin}{%
    \begin{mybox}{\insertblocktitle}{gray}\noindent%
}
\setbeamertemplate{block example end}{\end{mybox}}


\begin{document}
This is some text outside any frame.

\begin{mybox}{The title}{gray}\noindent
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris ac feugiat 
    nisi. Donec vitae pretium magna. Sed eget mi felis. Morbi luctus quis nulla 
    nec eleifend. Suspendisse et justo ex. Ut at quam a dui auctor tempor. 
    Proin elementum lacus turpis. Praesent blandit sollicitudin ipsum, a 
    eleifend metus gravida non.
\end{mybox}
    

\begin{frame}{Frame}
    \begin{exampleblock}{Block}
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris ac feugiat 
        nisi. Donec vitae pretium magna. Sed eget mi felis. Morbi luctus quis nulla 
        nec eleifend. Suspendisse et justo ex. Ut at quam a dui auctor tempor. 
        Proin elementum lacus turpis. Praesent blandit sollicitudin ipsum, a 
        eleifend metus gravida non.
    \end{exampleblock}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to remove the `\noindent`:

```
 \documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}
%\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{beamerarticle}

\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2]{
    lower separated=false,
    colback=white,
    colframe={#2},
    fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries,
    % fontupper=\bfseries\sffamily,
    colbacktitle={#2},
    coltitle=white,
    before upper=\par\noindent{},
    enhanced,
    attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-0.1in,xshift=0.15in},
    boxed title style={boxrule=0pt,colframe=white,},
    title={\color{white}{#1}}
}
\setbeamertemplate{block example begin}{%
    \begin{mybox}{\insertblocktitle}{gray}%
}
\setbeamertemplate{block example end}{\end{mybox}}


\begin{document}
This is some text outside any frame.

\begin{mybox}{The title}{gray}\noindent
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris ac feugiat 
    nisi. Donec vitae pretium magna. Sed eget mi felis. Morbi luctus quis nulla 
    nec eleifend. Suspendisse et justo ex. Ut at quam a dui auctor tempor. 
    Proin elementum lacus turpis. Praesent blandit sollicitudin ipsum, a 
    eleifend metus gravida non.
\end{mybox}
    

\begin{frame}{Frame}
    \begin{exampleblock}{Block}
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris ac feugiat 
        nisi. Donec vitae pretium magna. Sed eget mi felis. Morbi luctus quis nulla 
        nec eleifend. Suspendisse et justo ex. Ut at quam a dui auctor tempor. 
        Proin elementum lacus turpis. Praesent blandit sollicitudin ipsum, a 
        eleifend metus gravida non.
    \end{exampleblock}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Anyway, I cannot figure why `\noindent` includes a space ?

Comment: @Ger I didn't actually check where the space some from, but my guess would be some interaction between `\noindent` and the checks tcolorbox performs at the start of the body to see if there is normal text, a list etc. Given that I don't see a good reason to use `\noindent` at this position, I don't think it matters a lot where the space is from.